# How to adjust web layout along with header, navigation etc to maximum width using css?

Tags: html, css

As I was looking at websites, I've noticed that when you zoom out in your browser. The design of the header, navigation, content area and footer expands along with the layout. I've also found out that most of the website follow that model like pcworld, microsoft, facebook etc. Just like example below:

**This is Zoom 100%:**
[image]

**Then, this is Zoom 50%. Notice how the header and navigation also expands:**

[image]

**Rather than this one, which is boxed and you can see alot of these in tutorials:**

[image]

**I would like to know how to do it by providing an example of how to write it in css, similar to techcrunch website is highly appreciated.**

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial, explain a technique or provide any other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about responsive web design

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BIz02qY5BRA
(I learned a lot from here)

This basiclly makes the website respond to the window/device size. You can do this by making a website then using media queries. For example

Html file

```
<p class="color"> Hello </p>
```

CSS file

```
color {color: blue;}

@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) {
color {color: red;}
       }
```

This would make it so when the width of device/window will reach 800px it will change "Hello" to red instead of blue.
But this is just a small example, you can do much more after knowing the basics!